# How do I make separate Menu/MenuItem in a React/MUI navbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm making a navbar for an application and am having some trouble with separating multiple Menu/MenuItem. Whatever I try, both Menus and their MenuItems link to the same place.

Here's my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem'; 

const Navbar = (props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const logout = () => {
        props.onAuthenticated(false);
        navigate('/');
    };

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Button component={Link} to='/'>Home</Button>
            <Button
                id="basic-button-1"
                aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu-1' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                Movies
            </Button>
            <Button
                id="basic-button-2"
                aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu-2' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                Actors
            </Button>
            <Menu
                id="basic-menu-1"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                MenuListProps={{
                'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button-1',
                }}
            >
                <MenuItem component={Link} to='/movies' onClick={handleClose}>All</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem component={Link} to='/movies/create' onClick={handleClose}>Create</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <Menu
                id="basic-menu-2"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                MenuListProps={{
                'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button-2',
                }}
            >
                <MenuItem component={Link} to='/actors' onClick={handleClose}>All</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem component={Link} to='/actors/create' onClick={handleClose}>Create</MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            {(props.authenticated) ? (
                <Button variant='outlined' onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
            ) : ""}

        </Grid>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

In the above code, the NavBar created contains a 'Home', 'Movies' and 'Actors' headings, and the 'Movies' and 'Actors' dropdowns work, but both of them link to the /actors pages. I tried a few things like creating separate anchorEls, opens and handlers, but that actually reversed the problem, and both 'Movies' and 'Actors' started linking to /movies rather than /actors. I can't seem to get them both to link to where they're supposed to go, and I can't help but think I'm missing something simple.

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to dynamically set the anchors depending on the buttons name.

**States / functions :**

```js
 const [anchorState, setAnchorState] = useState({
    btn1: null,
    btn2: null,
  });

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setAnchorState({ [e.target.name]: e.currentTarget });
  };

  const handleClose = (e) => {
    setAnchorState({ [e.target.name]: null });
  };
```

**Buttons :**

```js
      <Button
        id="basic-button-1"
        aria-controls={Boolean(anchorState.btn1) ? "basic-menu-1" : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={Boolean(anchorState.btn1) ? "true" : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
        name="btn1"
      >
        Movies
      </Button>

      <Button
        id="basic-button-2"
        aria-controls={Boolean(anchorState.btn2) ? "basic-menu-2" : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={Boolean(anchorState.btn2) ? "true" : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
        name="btn2"
      >
        Actors
      </Button>
```

**Menus :**

```js
      <Menu
        id="basic-menu-1"
        anchorEl={anchorState.btn1}
        open={Boolean(anchorState.btn1)}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": "basic-button-1",
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem component={Link} to="/movies" onClick={handleClose}>
          All
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem component={Link} to="/movies/create" onClick={handleClose}>
          Create
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      <Menu
        id="basic-menu-2"
        anchorEl={anchorState.btn2}
        open={Boolean(anchorState.btn2)}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": "basic-button-2",
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem component={Link} to="/actors" onClick={handleClose}>
          All
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem component={Link} to="/actors/create" onClick={handleClose}>
          Create
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
```

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly! Thank you so much Julien, I really appreciate it.